# Can I Specify Icon Sizes of a Windows 8 Start Tile for a Chrome App

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome-app

When I right click on the shortcut for my Chrome App in the start screen on Windows 8.1, there are two options to re-size: Small and Medium.

Other tiles, like Weather, can be re-sized as Small, Medium, Wide, and Large.

Can I specify these icon sizes for my Google Chrome Extension?

I tried adding to the manifest.json file

```
"icons": {
  "128": "icon_128.png",
  "Wide": "Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png"
},
```

but it doesn't add a "Wide" re-sizing option.

Comment: Is that an _extension_ or an _app_? I don't understand how you can make a shortcut for an extension.

Comment: If you're talking about an app, it's an interesting question. The current manifest structure does not allow it, but it sounds like a good feature request to support tile images for app shortcuts on Windows. You can file a request at https://crbug.com/

Comment: I might have my terminology mixed up.  I install it locally in Chrome by opening chrome://extensions/, clicking the "Load unpacked extention..." button, and pointing it to the appropriate folder in my repository.  This is why I'm referring to it as an extension.  But it also shows up under chrome://apps/

Comment: So, it looks like the answer is, "No".  Xan, would you like to submit an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: The answer is "Not yet", and you should: 1) submit a feature request, 2) answer your own question with a link to said request. I think it's a reasonable feature to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, however I have submitted a feature request and will update this answer if this feature is implemented in the future.

The Issue can be viewed here: [Issue 432154](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=432154)